# Get first element in vector in Scheme

Tags: arrays, vector, scheme

Let's say that I create a vector/array in Scheme:

```
(let* ((x #(1 2 3)))
  (list-ref x 0)) ; returns error
```

What syntax or function can I use in the place of that list-ref to get `1`?

EDIT: I'm using Script-Fu with GIMP 2.8, where `array-ref` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `vector-ref`... (e.g., http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_8.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression`(define v '#(1 2 3))` is shorthand for creating a new *vector*, in standard Scheme it's equivalent to this:

```
(define v (list->vector '(1 2 3)))
```

Or this:

```
(define v (make-vector 3))
(vector-set! v 0 1)
(vector-set! v 1 2)
(vector-set! v 2 3)
```

Once a vector is created (using any of the mentioned procedures), the correct way to access an element in a vector is by calling the `vector-ref` procedure - clearly, because it's a *vector* and not a *list* of elements:

```
(vector-ref v 0)
```

In the previous expression, `v` is the vector and `0` the index whose element we want to retrieve. Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.gimp.org/docs/script-fu-update.html) for a more detailed explanation of the procedures outlined above.

Comment: This is going to be picky, but when you mention "standard scheme" such pickiness is justified...  In at least r5rs and up, `#(...)` is not specified.  Instead, you should quote it: `'#(...)`.  (It is similar for `()` not being a valid shorthand for `'()`.)  And since it's quoted, there's the usual distinction between such a literal and an expression that constructs a new vector.

Comment: vector-ref doesn't work on any floating point vector.  There is no function overloading or dynamic dispatch.  you need a different function for every element type and schemes simply don't provide that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `vector-ref` for this purpose. For example:

```
(vector-ref x 0)
```

[Here](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_sec_6.3.6) is a link to the R<sup>5</sup>RS spec's section on vectors, which provides more information.

Comment: Oh, wow. That's something that I should have been able to figure out.